# replacing in dataframe based on list/array

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

If I have an array/list like such,

```
(['Alabama', 'Arizona', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah'])
```

and I have a dataframe column where those values in the array are present and repeating, how do I replace them based on the location's index in the array? eg my column has Alabama which has an index 0, so for all the Alabama in the column, I would like to replace it with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"States": ['Alabama', 'Arizona', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah',
                              'Alabama', 'Arizona', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah']})

print(df)
```

[image: The dataframe]

Then you could apply the index like this:

```py
# Here is the list of states for which you want the index
indexList = (['Alabama', 'Arizona', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah'])

# Replace the state names with the respective index
df["States"] = df["States"].apply(indexList.index)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    States
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        0
8        1
9        2
10       3
11       4
12       5
13       6
```

As you can see,

- `Alabama` was replaced with the number `0`.
- `Arizona` was replaced with the number `1`.
- etc etc